# CGAffineTransforms on NSViews

Tags: objective-c, rotation, nsview, quartz-2d, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to port some iOS code to Mac OS X. I am having trouble porting this though,

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRoatation(-b->GetAngle());    
oneView.transform = transform
```

How can I achieve this? The NSView doesn't have a transform property.

Answer (score 4):

You still can use transformations.

Make sure your view is layer-backed by setting `setWantsLayer:` on your view to `YES`.

Afterwards, you can just set the layer's affine transform:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-b->GetAngle());    
[[oneView layer] setAffineTransform: transform];
```

Comment: i have the same issue currently. the problem is that apple says - _When using layer-backed views you should never interact directly with the layer_ because the layer could be updated somewhere else inside NSView.

Comment: @Remi: Ah, I didn't know that.  Well then, you might want to make a new question and see if anyone can help you!

Answer (score 0):

The only way i found to rotate NSView with core animation is

```
[myView setFrameCenterRotation:angle]
```

but be carefull using this method. it works correct only if myView is added to a superview.
you can track this by overriding method `– viewWillMoveToSuperview:`

Enjoy)